# JQuery select the next similar elements

Tags: jquery

Say we have markup:

```
 <h1 id="heading1">Heading 1</h1>
 <p>Paragraph 1</p>
 <p>Paragraph 2</p>
 <p>Paragraph 3</p>
 <p>Paragraph 4</p>
 <p>Paragraph 5</p>
 <h2 id="heading2">Heading 2</h2>
```

**Question: How will I select the 5 'p' elements after #heading1?**
I tried the code below but it doesn't meet my expectations:

```
 jQuery('#heading1").next(p);
```

It will only select the first **'p'** that contains 'Paragraph 1' text.

**Any solution?**

Comment: you want to select all p after h1 and before h2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `nextUntil()`.

It will select all the following siblings and quit when it encounters selector passed as argument

```
jQuery('#heading1').nextUntil('h2');
```

Not sure what the next main element is but know that you want `<p>` tags only you can use:

```
 jQuery('#heading1').nextUntil(':not(p)');
```

**[nextUntil() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)**

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XEmNJ/)**</kbd>

Comment: Awesome. I think this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$("#heading1").nextAll("p").eq(4)
```

4 is 5th "p", index start from 0

http://jsfiddle.net/6GBa7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`:header`](http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/)** pseudo selector which works will all types of headers.

```
jQuery('#heading1').nextUntil(':header')
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pGdBL/)**